# Looking for an equation in range of values

Tags: derivatives

Lets assume

T = 195;

T = 0; when x = 2;

T = 195; when x = 4;

What is the relation between T and x?

Comment: Would a line work here?

Comment: such as $T=195(x-2)/2$?

Comment: yes, is it the answer?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks for the answer, its working as expected

Comment: You wrote $'{T=195}'$ and '$T=195$ when $x=4$'.  Was the first a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T(x)=195(x-2)/2$ is a linear function with $T(2)=0$ and $T(4)=195$.

There is a linear relationship between two points.

I found it by eyeballing, but if you wanted to be pedantic you would solve

$T(x)=ax+b, T(2)=2a+b=0,$ and $T(4)=4a+b=195.$

You would get $(4a+b)-(2a+b)=2a=195$ and $b=-2a=-195$.

Comment: Thanks, it is working as expected and also thanks for this detailed explanation